# keras: add constant number to all input values

Tags: tensorflow, keras, tensorflow2.0

I want to create a simple toy model in keras. The model should take an input, then add a 1 to every element and produce an output.

I found an example using keras, but it requires 2 inputs

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras import layers

# create model
input1 = layers.Input(shape=(2,))
input2 = layers.Input(shape=(2,))
added = layers.Add()([input1, input2])
model = keras.models.Model(inputs=[input1, input2], outputs=added)

# run inference
input_shape = (2,)
x1 = tf.ones(input_shape)
x2 = tf.ones(input_shape)
y = model([x1, x2])
```

However, I need the model to only have a single input and simply increase every input value by 1, for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can replace the second input of your toy model with a call to  [`tf.ones_like`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/ones_like):

```
input1 = layers.Input(shape=())
added = layers.Add()([input1, tf.ones_like(input1)])
model = keras.models.Model(inputs=input1, outputs=added)
```

`tf.ones_like` creates a tensor full of ones of the shape of the tensor passed as an argument. As this op depends only on the shape of the input tensor, you can technically create your network without a specified input shape, and it will accept any shape as input:

```
>>> model(3)
<tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=float32, numpy=4.0>
>>> model(tf.ones((1,2,3)))
<tf.Tensor: shape=(1, 2, 3), dtype=float32, numpy=
array([[[2., 2., 2.],
        [2., 2., 2.]]], dtype=float32)>
```